# SPGridView - How to make it look & feel like built-in SP grid

Tags: 2010, document-library, splist, spgridview

In C# code, I'm working with the SPGridView control to display list items from a list of type SPDocumentLibrary. It binds fine, but it looks totally plain and has basically no features. I would like it to behave (with the standard SP context menu for documents, including checkout, view, etc., and also be sortable) and look just like a regular SP document list view.

Comment: I've found that the SharePoint:ListView control has most of this functionality.

Comment: I am also trying the same. Do you have any example??

Comment: I could not find any examples

Comment: just leave away the borders and set the width to 100%

Comment: Do you found way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16

SP GridView Sample Code with C sharp

Comment: Please don't add link only answers. If the link breaks in the future, your answer is of no value - so please add context of the link in your answer here, thank you